# Path component of a topological space containing $x_0$ contains all the loops based at $x_0$.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $C$ be a path component of $X$ containing the point $x_0 \in X$. Can we say that $\pi_1 (C,x_0) \cong \pi_1 (X,x_0)$?

What I think is as follows $:$

If we can show that all the loops based at $x_0$ are in $C$ then we are through. Suppose $\exists$ a loop at $x_0$ which is not entirely lying in $C$. Then $\exists$ a point $x$ on that loop such that $x \notin C$.  But since $x$ is arcwise connected to $x_0$ via that loop and any point in $C$ is connected to $x_0$ so any point in $C$ is connected to $x$. Then $C \cup \{x \}$ becomes a path connected space in $X$ strictly containing $C$, which contradicts the fact that any path component of $X$ is the maximal path connected space in $X$. This proves our claim and we are done with the proof.

Please verify it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's fine. Just note that $S^1$ is path connected, so the image of any map $S^1\rightarrow X$ is contained in a maximal path component, as is any homotopy $S^1\times I\rightarrow X$ for the same reasons.

Comment: On second thoughts, your proof only takes about *maps*, not about homotopy classes. You have shown that any class $\alpha\in\pi_1X$ can be represented by a map $\alpha':S^1\rightarrow C$, but if $\alpha\simeq\beta$ is a homotopy in $X$, then you need to show that $\alpha'\simeq\beta'$ in $C$. (It's not much more than you've done).